# SearchReturn in a Linked List

Tags: java, linked-list

I'm trying to get my searchReturn function to work but can't seem to get it. Also, It says I have to call my current somewhere else But i'm not sure how else to do it, so I listed it as private Node current; in the beginning of my code. I'm also having issues trying to increment the i so that when it reaches whatever number in my test file it returns that node.

Here's my searchReturn function:

```
public class List {
 private Node head;
 private int length;
 private Node current;

//Making the LinkedList, with the head as a new Node
//and the size of the list set to 0
public List(){
    length = 0;
}

public boolean isEmptyList(){
    if (length == 0){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}

//SearchReturn(L, key): returns a pointer to the Node to the index
public Node searchReturn(int key) {
    Node current = head;
    while(current != null) {
        key++;
    }
    return current;
}
```

Comment: your while loop looks like infinite loop buddy... you are not changing current value at all... you are just incrementing key values. To check insert a System.out.println to print current node contents.. and you will understand what i am talking about

Comment: @ShreyasSarvothama, thats what i was thinking too, which is why i had this before: `public Node searchReturn(int key) {
  Node current = head;
  while(int i < key; i++) {
   current = current.getNext();
  }
  return current;` but that wasn't working too well either

Comment: copy paste your entire code, you are not moving your current code.. I feel there is a logical bug in your program. How you insert all that code paste it in your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to advance the node to the next one `key` times:

```
public Node searchReturn(int key) {
    Node retVal = head;
    int i = 0;
    while(i < key) {
        if (retVal == null) {
            return null;
        }
        retVal = retVal.next();
        i++;
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but what is retVal?

Comment: @Jim a local variable used to hold the **val**ue you want to **ret**urn. It's defined in the first line of the method.

Comment: I Keep getting this error when I try to run my test file against my program: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 Any idea why it still says NullPointer even after I edited the searchReturn?

Comment: @Jim please share your test and the stacktrace.

Comment: it's a bit long for the test So here's the test link http://pastebin.com/rErheKYf, and this is my entire code linkedlist code, i have a node one as well but that shouldn't be interfering with this: http://pastebin.com/c1QCtvEz